# Exclusive input checkboxes - enable to uncheck by clicking on current checked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I did an exclusive menu of 2 `input checkboxes` : each `input checkbox` corresponds to a different case : (Player Vs Computer) and (Player1 Vs Player2) and each case is associated to `2 buttons` (which work as I want).

My issue is that I would like to add a functionality, i.e enable to uncheck the current checked box by clicking on the current checkbox (this one which is already checked).

For the moment, I have to click directly on the other `input checkbox` to uncheck the current one; I would like to get the both functionalities.

Here's the current code which handles these 2 exclusive `input checkbox` :

```
// Check input checked
 checkBoxState = $('#'+gameType+'').find('.game').prop('checked');
// Set oneButtonClicked to no for restore
 $('#formGame').prop('oneButtonClicked', 'no');
 // Handling input.game
 $('#'+gameType+'').find('.game').prop('checked', !checkBoxState);
 //$('#'+gameType+'').siblings().find('.game').prop('checked', checkBoxState);
 // Set pointer-events to all for formGame
 $('#formGame').css('pointer-events', 'all');
 // Handling button.btn
 $('#'+gameType+'').find('.btn').css('pointer-events', 'none');
 $('#'+gameType+'').siblings().find('.btn').css('pointer-events', 'all');
 $('#'+gameType+'').find('.btn').prop('disabled', checkBoxState);
 $('#'+gameType+'').siblings().find('.btn').prop('disabled', !checkBoxState);
```

`gameType` is the current type of game (Player Vs Computer or Player1 Vs Player2).

`input.game` represent the input checkboxes

`button.btn`represent the 2 buttons available for each `ìnput.game`.

How can I add this functionality, i.e uncheck by clicking on current checked, or uncheck by clicking directly on the other checkbox?

### Update 1

A click on a checkbox should automatically set its negation to the other checkbox.

### Update 2

I tried to adapt the solution given by **@CodeAt30** by doing simply:

```
gameType = (gameType == 'PlayerVsComputer') ? 'Player1VsPlayer2' : 'PlayerVsComputer'; 
 $('#'+gameType).find('.game').prop('checked',  !$('#'+gameType).find('.game').prop('checked'));
```

This solution works for uncheck the current checkbox and check its siblings().

But now, I can't select directly the other checkbox unlike to the JS Fiddle: [Uncheck checkbox by clicking directly on the other no-checked "input checkbow"](https://jsfiddle.net/8r12um8z/1/)

Comment: Whats about using radio button?

Comment: radio button would probably be the best solution indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/m059rr88/

**HTML**

```
<input id="one" type="checkbox"></input>
<input id="two" type="checkbox"></input>
```

**Javascript:**

```
let afterFirstClick = false;

$("input").click(function(){
        let passiveCheckboxId = "one";
        if($(this).attr("id") === "one"){
          passiveCheckboxId = "two"
    }
    if(afterFirstClick){
          $("input#" + passiveCheckboxId).prop("checked", !$("input#" + passiveCheckboxId).prop("checked"));
    }
    afterFirstClick = true;
});
```

Comment: -@CodeAt30. I tried to adapt your solution but I can only uncheck the current checkbox by clicking on it . BUT I can't set the other check box by cliking directly on the siblings() (the only one) of input checkbox. Could you take a look please in my **UPDATE 1** ?

Comment: @youpilat13 I don't think i follow you excatly. Could you maybe make a simplified jsfiddle version with html and js I could see?

But also, I gave the answer for learning purposes but I honestly think a radio button definition of the would be the simplest correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than you might think:

```
$('input.game').click(function(){
        $('input.game').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
```

What is does is assign a click handler to the checkboxes that removes the checked attribute from all other boxes. The status of the current box is handled by the native checkbox code, so checking and unchecking will work normally.

... or ...

```
$('input.game').click(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('input.game').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
            $('input.game').not(this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

This code will allow you to swap checkboxes by clicking on either one. Once a box is checked there is no way to uncheck it, like a radio button.

Comment: it seems that unchecking works with your solution but I forgot to say that I would like to get the other box checked by clicking on the current checked one.

Comment: So you want it to work like a radio button that allows toggling by clicking on either value?

Comment: yes, I realize that radio buttons is a solution ,thanks